# Opening a dialog when an Android live wallpaper is touched

Tags: android, dialog, live-wallpaper, touch-event

I’d like to open a dialog box with some simple information on it when a live wallpaper is tapped. Overriding onCommand in an Android live wallpaper, and adding a custom dialog almost straight out of the Android docs (with a layout info_dialog.xml not shown):

```
@Override
public Bundle onCommand (String action, int x, int y, int z, Bundle extras, boolean resultRequested)
{
 System.out.println(action);  
 Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog);
 dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

 TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
 text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");

 dialog.show();

 return null
}
```

just generates an exception:

```
12-02 07:14:40.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
12-02 07:14:40.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)

12-02 07:14:40.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)

12-02 07:14:40.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)

12-02 07:14:40.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
```

I’m assuming this is because I’m trying to raise the dialog from a WallpaperService rather than from an Activity. Overriding the WallpaperService.Engine’s onTouchEvent method just gets the same result.

Does this mean that I need to spin up a separate Activity to host the dialog?  Or is triggering a dialog from a live wallpaper not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that I need to spin up a separate Activity to host the dialog?

Yes. Or, better yet, use a dialog-themed activity.

Personally, if you are expecting to do this for your whole live wallpaper, I expect you will get a whole bunch of one-star ratings on the Market, as I suspect that users will get irritated when your activity/dialog keeps popping up just because they mis-tap on their home screen.

Comment: 1/ Sounds good, I'll take a look at a dialog-themed activity.

Comment: 2/ Well, it'd make me angry. Good point :) I guess you *could* have a specific tappable region, but even so ..

Comment: 3/ So what's the accepted way of providing information about a live wallpaper -- having something like an "About" option in the wallpaper settings?

Comment: @Tim Barrass: "I guess you could have a specific tappable region" -- precisely. "So what's the accepted way of providing information about a live wallpaper -- having something like an "About" option in the wallpaper settings?" -- off the cuff, I'd have an activity in the launcher for that. Bear in mind that I'm not much of a live wallpaper user, so my opinions may be less than relevant.

Comment: sounds reasonable. Thanks for the ideas!